# I'm trying to make a POST request to get receive access token, however I'm receiving undefined. How can I resolve this please?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, fetch-api

I'm trying to make a POST request to receive access token, however the function isn't returning anything and I get undefined. How can I resolve this please?

```
function getOAuth() {
    fetch("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", {
      method: "POST",
      body:
        "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=" +
        clientId +
        "&client_secret=" +
        clientSecret,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      }
    })
      .then(resp => resp.json()
        // Return the response as JSON
      )
      .then(function(data) {
        // Log the API data
        console.log("token", data);

        // Store token data
        let token = {
          token: data.access_token,
          tokenType:data.token_type,
          expires: new Date().getTime() + data.expires_in * 1000
        }
        return token
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        // Log any errors
        console.log("something went wrong", err);
      });
  }
```

Comment: Where do you get `undefined` ?

Comment: Is data undefined in your ```console.log("token", data)```? Or is the entire ```get0Auth``` function returning undefined?

Comment: no when I console.log(data), I get a response. But the function itself returns undefined when I call it

Comment: Ah I see. I think this is an async issue. Answer posted below.

Answer (score 0):

The function looks fine, I would assume that the problem is lying in the request to the server. Probably there is some mistake with the url or the body or header of the post request. Maybe it is also something like adding `mode: 'cors'` to your post request. I sadly don't know the spotify api good enough to help you with that though.

Answer (score 0):

What's probably happening is the that the code below this function is getting called before it finishes. You can use async and await to force the code beneath this function to wait for it to finish.

Redefine your function like this:

```
async function getOAuth() {
...code here
}
```

then when using the function, use it like this:

```
const token = await get0Auth();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no return statement in the function, just add it like that:

```
return fetch("https://accou...
```

Then you can call the function with `async/await`

```
const token = await getOAuth();
```

or using the old `then()` style

```
getOAuth().then(token => console.log(token));
```